# Simple rewriting rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Ok, maybe I'm dump, but my simple rewrite .htacces rule doesn't work. I just want on my site for example www.mysite.com/something.html rewrite rule to www.mysite.com/something . I yust want to remove .html and getting content from file something.html

Now I have this in my .htacces file, but not working:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another rule for redirecting `.html`:

```
RewriteEngine On

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html
```